# UIImagePickerController returns different image sizes for iPhone 3Gs and 4s

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm picking an image using `UIImagePickerController` . In iPhone 4s, the image looks like

[image]

And when I use an iPhone 3GS the image looks like this

[image]

3gs images look blurred.

I don't know why this is so. Here's how I'm fetching the images.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    if ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:@"public.image"]) 
    {
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];            
        imgPicker = nil;
        UIImage * userOriginal = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        NSLog(@"orinal image Image size: (%f, %f)",
              userOriginal.size.width, userOriginal.size.height);
     }
}
```

Comment: Well, you should expect that, the cameras are quite different.

Comment: so we do any thing for this issue

Comment: I have no idea of what your app does, it's up to you to choose how you want to handle different resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

UIImagePickerController returns images at the highest quality and resolution that the camera can capture - and this is different for all iOS devices.

If you want a standardized output, you will have to manually resize the image returned.